# Function to monitor and count another function Python

Tags: python, function, count, monitor, higher-order-functions

Write a function **make_monitored** that takes as input a function, f, that itself takes one input. The result returned by make_monitored is a third function, say mf, that keeps track of the number of times it has been called by maintaining an internal counter.

If the input to mf is the special string "how-many-calls?", then mf returns the value of the
counter.

If the input is the special string "reset-count", then mf resets the counter
to zero. For any other input, mf returns the result of calling f on that input and
increments the counter.

```
def make_monitored(f):
    a=[0]
    def mf(x):
        if x=="how-many-calls?":
            return a[0]
        elif x=="reset-count":
            a=[0]
        else:
            a[0]+=1
            return f(x)
    return mf


def double(x): #NOT TO BE CHANGED , provided by question
    return 2 * x

d = make_monitored(double)  #NOT TO BE CHANGED, provided by question
```

**here is what i dont understand:**
I want to make a one element list to make as an internal counter. I dont get why they say a is not defined when make_monitored is the parent function and i have defined a.

This is another question that i have completed previously (and correctly) that makes use of a similar method, but succeeds.

An accumulator is a function that is called repeatedly with a single numeric argument
and accumulates its arguments into a sum. Each time it is called, it returns
the currently accumulated sum. Write a function make_accumulator that generates
accumulators, each maintaining an independent sum.

```
def make_accumulator():
    lst=[0]
    def add(x):
        lst[0]+=x
        return lst[0]     
    return add
A=make_accumulator()
```

Sample execution:

A = make_accumulator ()

A(10)  output :10

A(10)  Output :20

**I dont get why lst[0] is accepted to be defined here.**
The only possible reason is that make_accumulator takes in no parameters but
make_monitored does take in 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment `a = [0]` creates a new `a`, which is local to `mf`. And that means that all other references to `a` in `mf` must be to that local `a` instead of the one in the parent.

So avoid assigning to `a` itself and instead mutate it:

```
a[0] = 0
```

---

BTW, Python 3 provides a new keyword `nonlocal` which is handy for this sort of thing. It works similarly to the `global` keyword, and you could use it here to have a simple int for your counter or accumulator, rather than messing around with an int inside a mutable container.

Answer (score 1):

We're defining a [closure](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) - a function which is inside it's own environment. This lets our function keep track of extra state.

At the time of definition of our inner function, the variable a is assigned to a list with contents [0].

When you do this:

`elif x=="reset-count": a=[0]`
You are assigning a to a brand-new list that is local to our inner function; it no longer knows about the 'a' defined on the outside.

Use the nonlocal keyword to keep track of state in closures. E.G:

```
def count_calls(func):
    calls_so_far = 0
    def inner(x):
        nonlocal calls_so_far # this allows us to keep track of state
        if x == 'how-many-calls'
            return calls_so_far
        if x == 'reset-count':
            calls_so_far = 0
        else:
            calls_so_far += 1
            return func(x)
    return inner

 
@count_calls # this is a DECORATOR
def double(x):
    return 2*x

# This decorator is equivalent to the following:
"""
def double(x):
    return 2*x
double = count_calls(double)
"""
```

In Python 2, you can't use the nonlocal keyword. Instead, you have to mutate some kind of mutable container. Using a list and mutating the first element is a common approach, and the one seen in your example code. This is not intuitive and easy to make mistakes with, though, so the nonlocal approach is considered more idiomatic python.

SCOPE EXAMPLE FOR PYTHON 3.6 (try running it yourself!):

```
x = 'GLOBAL'
def outer():
    print('running outer()')
    x = 'OUTER'
    print(f'\tx = {x}')
    def inner():
        print('\t\trunning inner()')
        x = 'INNER'
    def inner_nonlocal():
        nonlocal x
        print('\t\trunning inner_nonlocal()')
        x = 'INNER_NONLOCAL'
    inner()
    print(f'\tx = {x}')
    inner_nonlocal()
    print(f'\tx = {x}')
    
print('before running outer()')
print(f'x = {x}')
outer()
print('after running outer()')
print(f'x = {x}')
```

Comment: im using python 3.6. So the only way is to use a mutable data structure like a list right?

Comment: No. You can use nonlocal.

I've edited in a didactic example of the scope rules and the use of nonlocal that might help.

Comment: I appreciate the help. It is very useful. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with Python in the future!